# Does the video player software I need for work exist?

Tags: software-recommendation, video

**Short version**: is there a video player for Ubuntu that will display timecode *from the video file* as well as give me a quick information window about bitrate, codec and audio configuration, a la QuickTime Player in MacOS?

**Long version**: I work in video post-production in an all-Mac environment; during the pandemic I have been remotely controlling my work computer (which is intricately tied in to a big complicated visual effects finishing processor) with an iMac. QuickTime Pro 422 is the standard for delivery in what I do, which is a bummer because Apple doesn't want to support QuickTime anymore, and so when getting a laptop I decided to try Windows 10.

I really didn't like the file structure and navigation, and on a whim decided to try Linux for the first time since high school with a quick install of elementary os. I really like elementary and very quickly got things a lot more functional than I had with Windows 10.

I can VPN into my office, screen-share with my machine and do all of my remote work great. The one problem I'm facing is QCing files, which I have to do locally. QuickTime Player 7 is what I use in a Mac environment, as it lets me both check timecode as well as quickly pull up a window showing me bitrate, audio codec, etc. [Example here of QuickTime Player 7 information window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIT4c.png)

Although I can do the latter in VLC, it doesn't give me timecode; the closest program I can find is DJV, which I can't get working on elementary OS and which - in the Mac version - doesn't seem to handle 5.1 audio correctly. Searching has not found me anything - does anyone have any application suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked in the 'Tools' menu in VLC? It has that info if you click things like 'Media Information'. I'm lost at the 'timecode' section - unless you mean showing the time. I am pretty sure every media player does that.

Comment: video.stackexchange.com might be better for you, there are dedicated QC apps with Linux versions though, like drastic.tv/productsmenu-56/videoiosoftwarelist/…. I've only used NLEs though really so I can't comment on suitability.
Actually thinking about what you're asking, I'd be surprised if KDEnLive, with the video logging layout didn't suit (View>Load Layout>Logging)? Or maybe Blender??

Answer (score 1):

You can try mpv. Shift+i will toggle codecs info and you can get timecodes in milliseconds if you really want it with editing config file (or just left clicking on current time). Shift+O will add timings in OSD.

[example in mpv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9babc.png)